# How to close a React Navigation modal with multiple screens in it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using https://reactnavigation.org/ for navigation in a React Native app with a tab navigator as the main stack and a modal with two screens in it (for logging in and configuring the app).

I can't for the life of me figure out how to close the modal from the second screen (`SelectItems`).  From the first screen in the modal I can close it with `navigation.goBack()`.

Both modal screens need a close button.  Is there a way to just return back to whatever tab the user was on?

Thanks in advance for any help.

```js
const Tabs = TabNavigator(
  {
    Search: { screen: Search },
    Settings: { screen: Settings }
  }
);

// modal with two screens
const Setup = StackNavigator(
  {
    Login: {
      screen: Login
    },
    SelectItems: {
      screen: SelectItems
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Login'
  }
);

const RootStack = StackNavigator(
  {
    Main: {
      screen: Tabs
    },
    Setup: {
      screen: Setup
    }
  },
  {
    mode: 'modal',
    headerMode: 'none'
  }
);
```

Answer (score 30):

Simple and easy solution for react-navigation 5.x ([getParent](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/navigation-prop#getparent) docs):

```
navigation.getParent()?.goBack();
```

This works because it grabs the navigator's parent, which is the modal and what you want to dismiss.

NOTE: In older versions of 5.x this was called `dangerouslyGetParent`. That exists in newer 5.x versions, but is now deprecated. Use that if `getParent` isn't available in the version of react-navigation that you're using. It isn't actually dangerous: From react-navigation's documentation:

> Reason why the function is called dangerouslyGetParent is to warn developers against overusing it to eg. get parent of parent and other hard-to-follow patterns.

Comment: This solved my issue, thank you so so much. I've been struggling with this for at least 2 hours. I was running into an issue where I would push a screen from a parent navigator on the stack, then when I went back, the current stack would nav back but the latest pushed screen (from the parent stack) would stay visible. Was driving me crazy. Thank you!!

Comment: Solved my issue as well! My stack was a wizard-like form, in which each step is a screen under a stack navigator. When finishing the whole thing or when canelling, I just needed to get rid of the whole navigator, so this exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 28):

I found a solution but it isn't perfect.

You can use the popToTop which will go back to the first Scene of your stack and than the goBack will close the modal.

```
navigation.popToTop();
navigation.goBack(null);
```

The problem with that is that it will mount again the first scene of the stack, so be sure you dont use `setState` in you willMount or didMount. Or prevent it.

That's the solution i'm going with for now. I keep looking for a better solution.

Comment: Any better solution now?

Answer (score 11):

This was my solution with v6 in 2022. It closes the modal and navigates away without any weird behaviors (at least in my case).

```js
onPress = () => {
    navigation.goBack(); // <-- this fixed it
    navigation.navigate("SomeScreen", { id: 123});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Stack Navigation** you can always move around in the **navigation stack** using `navigation.pop()`. For instance, if you want to close two open modals you can call the `pop` function with parameter value *2*:

```js
navigation.pop(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use react-navigation 4.x there is a method `navigation.dismiss()`. The method dismisses the entire stack and return to the parent stack

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/navigation-prop/#dismiss

Answer (score -1):

Original solution from https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/686#issuecomment-342766039, updated for React Navigation 4:

Create a `DismissableStackNavigator`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
export default function DismissableStackNavigator(routes, options) {

  const StackNav = createStackNavigator(routes, options);

  const DismissableStackNav = ({navigation, screenProps}) => {
    const { state, goBack } = navigation;
    const props = {
      ...screenProps,
      dismiss: () => goBack(state.key),
    };

    return (
      <StackNav
        screenProps={props}
        navigation={navigation}
      />
    );
  }

  DismissableStackNav.router = StackNav.router;
  return DismissableStackNav;
};
```

Usage:

1. Creating your stack:

```
// modal with two screens
const Setup = StackNavigator(
  {
    Login: Login,
    SelectItems: SelectItems
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Login'
    headerMode: 'none'
  }
);
```

2. Call `navigation.dismiss` in your screens to close the modal stack.

Comment: As of react-navigation@4, I managed that I should call `this.props.screenProps.dismiss()`

Answer (score -4):

I was trying to figure this myself and the solution I ended up using was to use `navigation.navigate()`

Example `this.props.navigation.navigate('name of screen you want to go');`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks :) I stuck with the deprecated React nav but I’m saving this for my next go around.

Comment: This answer is extremely outdated you need to use hooks in 2021