# react-navigation/native goBack bug on android

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I created multiple pages, but when I use `goBack()` on Android, I go back to the defaultView but can not press anything and the screen looks smaller than the usual.

My screens will be created like following:

```js
...
const cardOptions = {
  cardOverlayEnabled: true,
  gestureEnabled: true,
  ...TransitionPresets.ModalPresentationIOS,
}

export const MainStack: React.FC<Props> = ({ initialRouteName }) => {
  return (
    <PushProvider>
      <TopicCreateFormProvider>
        <WorkgroupCreateFormProvider>
          <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator
              screenOptions={{
                headerShown: false,
              }}
              initialRouteName={initialRouteName}
            >
              <Stack.Screen name="BottomTabs" component={BottomTabs} />
              <Stack.Group screenOptions={cardOptions}>
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="ScreenOne"
                  component={ScreenOne}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="ScreenTwo"
                  component={ScreenTwo}
                />
              </Stack.Group>
...
```

I navigate between the screens with ``` navigation.navigate('ScreenOne')`` from the ``` useNavigation` hook

Then I use on a screen `const { goBack } = useNavigation()` and trigger `goBack()` onPress on a Button.

Then the screen looks like this, and I am not able to interact with it.
[image]

---- EDIT ----

It seems to be a problem with the nested route.

Comment: If you use the inspector from the device debug menu, when does it say you are tapping on? might be a modal issue, where it navigates back but the modal is still present

Comment: @Krismu when I open the toggle the inspector, the modal apperes.

Comment: then have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49804332/how-to-close-a-react-navigation-modal-with-multiple-screens-in-it

Comment: @Krismu sadly this is outdated and do not work.

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: if you are on v6.x you can just use ```navigation.getParent()?.goBack()```

Comment: @Krismu yes I am using v6.x. I already tried `getParent()` but this still do not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237890/discussion-between-antoni-and-krismu).

Comment: @Krismu I found this at the docs https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#navigation-actions-are-handled-by-current-navigator-and-bubble-up-if-couldnt-be-handled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the issue. The problem is with `TransitionPresets.ModalPresentationIOS` when you use it in android the `goBack` something brokes. It seams that the screen will be not rendered, because whenn I toggle the inspector the screen appers.

Answer (score 0):

Try set detachPreviousScreen: false on your cardOptions

Comment: You answer would be better to posted as a comment rather than a post.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33300164)